# How can I setup Eclipse to compile single SASS Files?

Tags: eclipse, ant, sass

We're trying to setup Eclipse to automatically compile .sass files on change. However all answers to this on stackoverflow and on the internet allways compile ALL css files in a folder.

This is unacceptable for us because we have 58 CSS files in the folder, with a combined size of 142kb. Both on Windows and Mac it takes about 45 seconds to compile the files, and this happens after every save.

Is there a way to setup Eclipse / an Ant build file to compile only the one file that was saved?

Edit: Or is there a way to launch sass --watch ONCE when opening the project in Eclipse?

Comment: What's doing the compile?  I didn't think there was support for SASS files from eclipse.org.

Comment: In the examples I found here people made their own ant build files and added a new builder to the project, triggered by "Run the builder: [After a clean], [During manual builds], and [During auto builds]". This however doesn't seem to tell the ant file which sass file was affected, and all examples compile the whole folder.